# Accessing External IP on WAN from inside docker container, moving from docker compose to kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, migration

I have a docker container which is part of a micro service architecture, all part of the same docker compose file.
This architecture provides logging, configuration and database services.
From inside this docker container I want to connect to an external rabbit queue, located on the WAN, which I do not own and I cannot amend, all I have are login details etc.
I solved the problem with docker compose by using the network_mode:host for this container, which allows me to connect to the external ip address and also connect to the other services via localhost.
However when I port this to kubernetes this docker container it fails. I cannot connect to the other microservices using their service name and obviously localhost also fails. Is there a way to access the other services I have, and make http requests to an external none containerised rabbitqueue when running under kubernetes? Any help appreciated, I am new to kubernetes so keeping it simple would be really appreciated.

Comment: Hallo @Lee, where and how are you running your k8s cluster? Generally for connecting to other services in the same cluster by default you shouldn't have to configure anything but I'd check the network policy's of the cluster for inter cluster communication

Comment: You shouldn't need host networking for this use case.  Both the Docker and Kubernetes networking models should correctly resolve out-of-cluster DNS names (you may need a fully-qualified name) and route IP traffic correctly.  Can you provide a [mcve] of a case that doesn't work with the default networking setup?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. 
I have managed to resolve. 
I removed the host network and from the config I have the services use I set the IP for the host